# How create jinja2 extension?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I try to make extension for jinja2. I has written such code:

http://dumpz.org/12996/

But I receive exception: `'NoneType' object is not iterable`. Where is a bug?
That should return `parse`. Also what should accept and return `_media`?

Answer (score 12):

You're using a `CallBlock`, which indicates that you want your extension to act as a block.  E.g.

```
{% mytest arg1 arg2 %}
stuff
in
here
{% endmytest %}
```

`nodes.CallBlock` expects that you pass it a list of nodes representing the body (the inner statements) for your extension.  Currently this is where you're passing `None` - hence your error.

Once you've parsed your arguments, you need to proceed to parse the body of the block.  Fortunately, it's easy.  You can simply do:

```
body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endmytest'], drop_needle=True)
```

and then return a new node.  The `CallBlock` receives a method to be called (in this case `_mytestfunc`) that provides the logic for your extension.

```
body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endmytest'], drop_needle=True)  
return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_mytestfunc', args),[], [], body).set_lineno(lineno)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want your extension to be a block tag, e.g.

```
{% mytest arg1 arg2 %}
```

you shouldn't use `nodes.CallBlock`, you should just use `nodes.Call` instead, which doesn't take a body parameter.  So just do:

```
return self.call_method('_mytestfunc', args)
```

`self.call_method` is simply a handy wrapper function that creates a Call node for you.

I've spent a few days writing Jinja2 extensions and it's tricky.  There's not much documentation (other than the code).  The coffin GitHub project has a few examples of extensions [here](https://github.com/coffin/coffin/blob/master/coffin/common.py).

Comment: or set body to [] ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972458/help-with-custom-jinja2-extension ... anyhoo, this question is no more ... but at least your link is very helpful