# Help with custom Jinja2 Extension

Tags: python, jinja2

I've struggled to get this Jinja2 custom extension to work -- the docs weren't kidding when they said writing one was not for "civilians" -- and finally managed to arrive at this working code:

```
class WrapperExtension(Extension):

    tags = set(['wrap'])

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = parser.stream.next().lineno
        args = [parser.parse_expression()]
        args.append(nodes.Const(args[0].name))
        return nodes.CallBlock(
            self.call_method('_render', args),
            [], [], []).set_lineno(lineno)

    def _render(self, value, name, *args, **kwargs):
        if some_condition():
            return '<wrapper id="%s">%s</wrapper>' % (name, value)
        return value
```

As I said, this is now working. What I'm unsure about is why I need to return `nodes.CallBlock` in `parse()`, rather than `self.call_method()` (which returns a `nodes.Call` object). If anyone has any insight -- or can point me to a tutorial on writing extensions -- please do let me know.

Comment: I wrote a Jinaj2 extension a while ago...and have already forgotten everything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `parse()` is expected to return a statement node, such as `CallBlock` or `Assign`. `call_method()` returns an expression node, which you must wrap in `CallBlock` to have a statement.